# SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

i created one ASP.Net project using SQL Server 2005 .I successfully inserted .But i dont know to view the table.Please tell me

Comment: We will need a littlew more detail than that. What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: You can browse your table using SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 2):

A beginner instrudciton into SQL server seems in order - you seem to stumble around not knowing anything about hwat you really deal with.

I suggest heading over to ASP.NET (http://www.asp.net/) and read the indroduction documentation, as well as have some look at the sample code and the beginner forum.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a pretty broad question, but to get data into a datatable you could do something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Retrieve", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
SqlDataAdapter sqldata = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
sqldata.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
```

Comment: soory i think i not explain the question detailed.MY question is I w
want to see the table in the database

Comment: The have a look at what @hallie said in a comment to your answer. You can view the table using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.